# Generator using two list of dictionaries

Tags: python, generator

I have two list of dictionaries called Reviewers_dicts and Products_dicts

The keys are the following:

```
Products_dicts = ['ProductID', 'sku', 'name_title', 'description', 'list_price', 'sale_price', 'category', 'category_tree', 'average_product_rating', 'product_url', 'product_image_urls', 'brand', 'total_number_reviews', 'Reviews', 'Bought With']

Reviewers_dicts = ['Username', 'DOB', 'State', 'Reviewed_ProductID']
```

I want to write a generator function that takes a username and yields all the reviews the person with that username has written, one at a time.

So far I have tried:

```
def find_reviews(val):
    for dict_key in reviewers_dicts
        if dict_key["Username"] == val1:
            if dict_key["Reviewed"] in reviewers_dicts == dict_key["ProductD"]:
                print(products_dicts["Reviews"])
```

Eaxmple entry for

```
prodcuts_dicts = {'uniq_id': 'b6c0b6bea69c722939585baeac73c13d','total_number_reviews': 8, 'Reviews': [{'User': 'fsdv4141', 'Review': 'You never have to worry about the fit...Alfred Dunner clothing sizes are true to size and fits perfectly. Great value for the money.', 'Score': 2}, {'User': 'krpz1113', 'Review': 'Good quality fabric. Perfect fit. Washed very well no iron.', 'Score': 4}, {'User': 'mbmg3241', 'Review': 'I do not normally wear pants or capris that have an elastic waist, but I decided to try these since they were on sale and I loved the color. I was very surprised at how comfortable they are and wear really well even wearing all day. I will buy this style again!', 'Score': 4}, {'User': 'zeqg1222', 'Review': 'I love these capris! They fit true to size and are so comfortable to wear. I am planning to order more of them.', 'Score': 1}, {'User': 'nvfn3212', 'Review': 'This product is very comfortable and the fabric launders very well', 'Score': 1}, {'User': 'aajh3423', 'Review': 'I did not like the fabric. It is 100% polyester I thought it was different.I bought one at the store apprx two monts ago, and I thought it was just like it', 'Score': 5}, {'User': 'usvp2142', 'Review': 'What a great deal. Beautiful Pants. Its more than I expected.', 'Score': 3}, {'User': 'yemw3321', 'Review': 'Alfred Dunner has great pants, good fit and very comfortable', 'Score': 1}], 'Bought With': ['898e42fe937a33e8ce5e900ca7a4d924', '8c02c262567a2267cd207e35637feb1c', 'b62dd54545cdc1a05d8aaa2d25aed996', '0da4c2dcc8cfa0e71200883b00d22b30', '90c46b841e2eeece992c57071387899c']}
```

Example entry for

```
Reviewers_Dicts = [{'Username': 'bkpn1412', 'DOB': '31.07.1983', 'State': 'Oregon', 'Reviewed': ['cea76118f6a9110a893de2b7654319c0']}, {'Username': 'gqjs4414', 'DOB': '27.07.1998', 'State': 'Massachusetts', 'Reviewed': ['fa04fe6c0dd5189f54fe600838da43d3']}]
```

Comment: Both variables (Products_dicts & Reviewers_dicts) are lists - not dictionaries

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please write your question so that we have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including what output you expected to see.

Comment: How do you store the values in your dictionaries?

Comment: `if dict_key["Reviewed"] in reviewers_dicts == dict_key["ProductD"]:` is not correct Python syntax. You should provide minimum samples of your data with un-needed values removed so it is clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Example of entries of the data has been edited to main post

Comment: I bet products_dicts is a LIST of dictionaries, just like Reviewers_Dicts: if so, you should add the `[ ]` around it. Furthermore, I'd suggest a change in the data structure: make products_dict an actual dict, its keys being the uniq_ids of the products, likes this: {'id1': {'sku: ... , 'name_title': ... , ...}, {'id2': {...}, ... }. And do the same for the reviewers_dict. Accessing what you need would become far more efficient (both code-wise and time-wise).

Comment: Oh and the change of structure goes for the 'Reviews': value in products_dict too. To sum it up, replace all your lists with dictionaries, keys being the primary values of your lists.

Comment: Oh, by the way, your example doesn't allow to really test code, since there's no user who reviewed the only product you presented...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming your `products_dicts` (typo fixed) actually is a list of several dicts, this code will do what you want:

```
def find_reviews(user):
    reviews = []
    for entry in Reviewers_Dicts:
        if entry['Username'] == user:
            prod_list = entry['Reviewed'] 
            break
    for prod_id in prod_list:
        for entry in products_dicts:
            if entry['uniq_id'] == prod_id:
                for rev in entry['Reviews']:
                    if rev['User'] == user:
                        yield rev['Review']
                        break
                break
```

That said, as I commented earlier, your data structure (lists of dicts, applying to products_dicts, Reviewers_Dicts, Reviews (in products_dicts)) is far for optimal, forcing the code to loop through each list to find the relevant entry, and would be better replaced with actual dicts fo dicts.

Comment: You're welcome, but seriously, think about your purpose and devise an appropriate data structure. If your lists are already done, you can always (and quite easily) convert them to a better data structure: for example, `rd = dict([[d['Username'], [d.pop('Username'),d][1]] for d in Reviewers_Dicts])` will turn your list of dicts into a dict of dicts, with far more efficient acces to a given user and will allow to replace the 1st `for` loop in my code with `prodlist = rd[user]['Reviewed']` .

Comment: The question asks for a generator function that yields all the reviews. But your answer does not do that, it returns a list of reviews.

Comment: Indeed, I'll edit that :)